# Spring Cloud Config Server - limitations on number of properties

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

We have a set of microservices that share the configuration. The configuration is huge - for now it is about 500k entries and there is more to be included. Is doesn't contain just keys and values, but also objects (that we build from several entries).

For example:

```
we.list.key1.field1 = 1A    
we.list.key1.field2 = 1B    
we.list.key1.field3 = 1C    
we.list.key2.field1 = 2A    
we.list.key2.field2 = 2B    
we.list.key2.field3 = 2C
```

we map to a bean as follows:

```
@Data
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("we")
public class OurProperties {

    private Map<String, OurBean> list;

}
```

where OurBean is defined like this:

```
@Data
public class OurBean {

    private String field1;
    private String field1;
    private String field1;


}
```

We are trying to use Spring Cloud Config Server + Rabbit for it, but we face performance problems - too little memory, read timeouts, service start timeouts. We are trying to tune the resources to make it work.
The question is, if this is reasonable option at all. Is SCCS suitable for such amount of data?

Any other options, if we need to share the configuration data between 100+ microservices and refresh them at once, after the data changes? Data doesn't change very frequently - lets assume a few times per week.

Comment: Do you use Spring Cloud Bus AMQP + RabbitMQ to push the changes to your microservices?

Comment: Yes. Upon change, a refresh event is sent to RabbitMQ and microservices refreshes their configuration after receiving the event.

Comment: Could you also provide the versions you use? or maybe the pom or gradle file?

Comment: Without knowing the versions, I would suggest trying Kafka instead of RabbitMQ, or even Pulsar, they have better performance than RabbitMQ. Also, Kafka has the `spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka`. Try them maybe you will see a significant difference in performance.  You can search for benchmarking and compare RabbitMQ VS Kafka VS Pulsar.

Comment: I assume that you use Kubernetes to deploy your microservices to the cloud. Another solution is to use ConfigMaps of the Kubernetes. [Check here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)